# Why does bootstrap use translate3d for their .nav-collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webkit

A recent ios 7.0 bug resulted in my nav menu not showing...  which has lead me to this question.

Why does bootstrap use `translate3d` on their mobile styles for their collapsable menu?

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .nav-collapse {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
     }
}
```

I had to override this to get the menu to show up on ios7.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .nav-collapse {
        -webkit-transform: none;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This forces the element to be rendered on a separate compositing layer in the GPU, making animations faster.

For more information, see [here](http://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/)

Comment: So in layman's terms, this is "helping" to speed up the slide down effect?